# Why do I need to open port 18083 when setting up p2pool mining?

Tags: mining, mining-pools

Is there an explanation as to what the command below is doing? Why does this port need to be opened?

`--zmq-pub tcp://127.0.0.1:18083`

from:
https://p2pool.io/#help

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need to open port 18083 when setting up p2pool mining? Is there an explanation as to what the command below is doing? Why does this port need to be opened?

Your p2pool node needs to *subscribe* to various changes on the Monero network, things like transactions being added to the transaction pool. To enable this, you run you Monero daemon with `--zmq-pub tcp://127.0.0.1:18083` which then allows your p2pool node to subscribe to various ZMQ events published on the specified host and port (127.0.0.1:18083).